# Map an http object to model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I'm having trouble mapping an http object to a model of mine, here's what I'm working with:

MyObjController.ts

```
class MyObjController {
        constructor (
            private myObj:myObjService,
            private $scope:angular.IScope,
            private modal,
            private notifier,
            private $translate,
            private $state,
            public items:MyObjModel[],
            public loading
        ) {
            this.loading = this.myObj.all();

            this.loading.then((allItems) => {
                this.items = allItems;
            });
        }
}
```

MyObjService.ts

```
all () : angular.IPromise<MyObjModel[]> {
            let uri = `/myuri`;

            return this.api.get(uri).then((response:any) => {
                return _.map(response.data, MyObjModel.create);
            });
        }
```

MyObjModel.ts

```
export class MyObjModel {
        constructor () { }

        id:string;
        name:string = '';
        organizationId:string = '';

        static create (apiResponse) {
            let model = new MyObjModel();

            model.id = apiResponse.Id;
            model.name = apiResponse.Name;
            model.organizationId = apiResponse.OrganizationId;

            return model;
        }
    }
```

This approach isn't working since _.map is sending each value from my response.data and creating a new instance of MyObjModel for each of the properties and then creating an array of the models. I'm looking for a way to send response.data as a whole to my create() function and have it map the values to a single instance of the model and return that single model.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the below code,

```
all () : angular.IPromise<MyObjModel[]> {
            let uri = `/myuri`;

            return this.api.get(uri).map(data=><MyObjController>data.json())).toPromise();
            });
        }
```

You can use interface instead of class and constructor which is the recommended practice as well

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit please? This doesn't seem to work and I'd like to know why you did certain things (like use MyObjController instead of the model) so I can try to make sense of it to fix it

Comment: you should not use `.then` when you are returning a promise as per your return type of the `all` method. You need not use the class to act as models instead just use interface.